# Textview inside popupwindow can't be selected

Tags: java, android, textview, popupwindow

I am having a simple textview inside a popupwindow with textIsSelectable enabled, however the text does not allowed any selection. I tried playing around with focus but nothing seems to work. Is this a bug or an intended behaviour of the popupwindow?

Side note, autoLink also requires double or even triple click to work.

Answer (score 0):

XML:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Capitalize your I.

Then in java:

```
Textview textViewId = findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
textViewId.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Comment: Well that's the way I have done it and works for fine textview inside fragments but fails for popupwindows.

Comment: How is the popup being created?  It might be that it's no longer treated as a "TextView" inside the popup.